# if and else in Aurelia.js

Tags: javascript, aurelia

How can I insert in the DOM a css class using aurelia.js?

If my `<th>` has the `class="aut-asc"` or `class="aut-asc"` , I would like to add a extra class called: `global`

aut-asc is added when it is clicked, fine but the thing is I need the th who has this class has red background.

now the background it is just in the arrow.

```
 .aut-desc:before{
        content: $fa-var-sort;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

if not don't do anything.

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="aut-asc">
      Sort
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: How are you adding `class="aut-asc"`? Can you not add `global` at the same time?

Comment: edited my question, thank you

Comment: So... why not add `global` when it's clicked as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can toggle adding and removing a css class from a variable using string interpolation:

```
 <th class="aut-asc ${toggleVariable ? 'global' : ''}">
```